# Removing boxes in a ytableau

Tags: tables, boxes, ytableau

I am attempting to draw a ytableau where I remove the boxes around the outermost part of the table. Basically, what I would like to do is remove the boxes around all of the numbers in the example below. Any Ideas on how to do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}

  \begin{ytableau}
    1 \\
    & 2 \\
    & & 3 \\
    & & & 4 \\
  \end{ytableau}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Remove the boxes around the numbers]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `ytableau` provides a command `\none` to make on empty box.  What it does not advertise so much is that this command takes an optional argument, the contents of that box.  So `\none[1]` will produce an unframed `1` as you request.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}

\begin{ytableau}
  \none[1] \\
  & \none[2] \\
  & & \none[3] \\
  & & & \none[4] \\
\end{ytableau}

\end{document}
```